# pdf field names from a locked pdf file

Tags: pdf, field, acrobat

I would like to extract pdf field names from a locked pdf file. When viewed in Acrobat Pro, I cannot edit. When viewed in notepad field names are not descernable.

[In case you want to try..  see here.](http://www.revenu.gouv.qc.ca/en/sepf/formulai%20res/lm/lm-1.aspx)

Thanks

Comment: This is probably a question better posed to superuser.com

Comment: there may be a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded the PDF into FoxIt Phantom (www.foxitsoftware.com) and exported the Form Data to an FDF file.  After a quick search and replace in a text editor to strip the unwanted data I came up with this list.

indiquez3
neq
nenr
cache1
cache2
indiquez2
choixA
gererImpotSocietes
gererSourceIndiquez2
date1
autreNom1
nomCom1
autreNomCom1
mme
appCom1
numeroCom1
rueCom1
villeCom1
provCom1
text_listeCodeCom1
libCodeCom1
listeCodeCom1
gererListeCom1
cpCom1
cpCom1_A
cpCom1_O
appAut1
numeroAut1
rueAut1
villeAut1
provAut1
text_listeCodeAut1
libCodeAut1
listeCodeAut1
gererListeAut1
cpAut1
cpAut1_A
cpAut1_O
appAut2
numeroAut2
rueAut2
text_listeCodeAut2
villeAut2
provAut2
libCodeAut2
listeCodeAut2
gererListeAut2
cpAut2
cpAut2_A
cpAut2_O
tel1
tel2
tel3
tel4
poste1
date2
telAut2
telAut3
langue1
langueAut1
dateAut2
dateAut3
dateAut4
caseFusion
prenom1
mmeA1
nas1
gererChoixA
app1
numero1
rue1
ville1
prov1
libCode1
listeCode1
cp1
cp1_A
cp1_O
gererListe1
text_listeCode1
telAut1
posteAut1
prenomA1
nasA1
appA1
numeroA1
rueA1
villeA1
provA1
libCodeA1
listeCodeA1
cpA1
cpA1_A
cpA1_O
gererListeA1
text_listeCodeA1
telA1
posteA1
mmeA2
nomA2
prenomA2
nasA2
appA2
numeroA2
rueA2
villeA2
provA2
libCodeA2
listeCodeA2
cpA2
cpA2_A
cpA2_O
gererListeA2
text_listeCodeA2
telA2
posteA2
mmeA3
nomA3
prenomA3
nasA3
telA3
posteA3
text_caseTaxe
caseTaxe
appA3
numeroA3
rueA3
villeA3
provA3
libCodeA3
listeCodeA3
cpA3
gererListeA3
text_listeCodeA3
cpA3_A
cpA3_O
caseRet
appT
numeroT
rueT
villeT
provT
libCodeT
listeCodeT
cpT
gererListeT
text_listeCodeT
cpT_A
cpT_O
caseImp
appR
numeroR
rueR
villeR
provR
libCodeR
listeCodeR
cpR
gererListeR
text_listeCodeR
cpR_A
cpR_O
appI
numeroI
rueI
text_listeCodeI
villeI
provI
libCodeI
listeCodeI
gererListeI
cpI
cpI_O
cpI_A
description
case4_2A
case4_2B
case4_2C
case4_2D
case4_2E
case4_2F
case4_2G
case4_2H
date3
dateTaxe1
ttlVentes
case5_3B
gererCase5_3B
case5_3B2
case5_3B3
case5_3B4
dateTaxe2
case6
case7
nom1
nomS
fonctionS
dateSource
dateS
gererCase6
nomA1
numero
indiquez4
indiquez1
cadreB
gererCaseImp
gererCaseRet
gererCaseTaxe
cadreDoc
prenez1
text5.3A
text5.3B
choix5
gererTaxes
gererChoix5
text_choix5
cadre1A
cadre1B
cadre1C
cadre2A
cadre2B
cadre2C
text_caseImp
case5_3A1
case5_3A2
case5_3B1_1
case5_3B1_2
text_choixA
E
case4_2I
case6A
case6C
case6B
case6E
case6G
case6H
case6I
case6J
case6K
case6L
case6D
case6F
blanc
fondBlanc

Comment: Another option would be to use a PDF library such as www.QuickPDF.com or www.itextpdf.com to read each form field and return you the name.  It would be simple to write a program to iterate through all Form Fields and fill in the value of the field with the field name and then save the PDF so that you have a visual reference of each field and it's name.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something?

Acrobat Pro -> Forms -> Export Data (xml)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work if the file is password protected.